# How to change button label in angularjs according to requirement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change the label of same button in angularjs according to requirement, same button can be for update and submit.

[See the following demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview),

Above demo is about the replicate the template. If some template has already data then label of submit button should be Update, other-wise for empty template label should be Submit.

I can't use following logic because it will change all button with same label, but I want to show label **Submit** only for empty and no-empty to show label **Update**. How I will do that?

```
<a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder($index)">{{btnText}}</a> 
And add some logic to your controller, that will specify text for button:

if (newItem){
  $scope.btnText = 'Submit';
}else{
  $scope.btnText = 'Update';
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-12" style="bottom:10px" >   
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in fields">  
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-4"> 
              <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Field1</label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input data-ng-model='field.field1' class="chosen-select input-md form-control sme-input-box"/>
              </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="col-md-4">          
            <label  class="col-md-12 control-label">Field2</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">            
                <input ng-model='field.field2'  class="chosen-select input-md form-control sme-input-box"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">            
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="removeTemplate($index)">Remove</a>   
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder($index)">Submit</a>   
            </div>                      
        </div>  
      </div>      
      <div class="col-md-3" style="top:5px">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="cloneTemplate()">Add</a>   
      </div>   
    </div>
```

**Angularjs**

```
  $scope.fields=[
            {
                "field1": "",
                "field2": "",
            }
        ]

        // update and get invoice details
        $scope.cloneTemplate=function(){
            var clone_template={ "field1": "", "field2": ""};
            $scope.fields.push(clone_template);
        }

        $scope.removeTemplate= function(templateIndex){
            $scope.fields.splice(templateIndex,1);
        }

        $scope.updateOrder=function(i){
            var updateOrder={
                "field1":$scope.fields[i].field1,
                "field2":$scope.fields[i].field2,
            }
            alert(updateOrder.field1);
            $http.post(config.server, updateOrder)
            .success(function(response, status){
                console.log(response);                
            })
            .error(function(response, status){
                console.log(response);
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that while while adding data you wanted to show `Submit` button label & show `Update` button label while updating record.

So as normal practice you are getting this value from the DB, so I'd suggest you to add `id` column in this object which will be there with fields. Now object will look like `{id: 1, field1: '1', field2: 2}` so if the element has id that means it has persisted in the database. And obviously if you don't have `id` in fields record means it has been added from UI.

So the whole logic will look at the `id` property of your object, if you have id in the record then it will show `Update` as button label otherwise it would be `Submit`

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder(field)" 
      ng-bind="field.id? 'Update': 'Submit'">
      Submit
   </a>   
</div>
```

So for make your logic working good, you need to get the list again from the database to make your UI consistent.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HUQtvk749XlajcPjtyiW?p=preview)

Comment: @geeks look at the updated answer with plunkr would help you more..while implementing the same :)

Comment: @geeks yes I had added plunkr too

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup for button to show some scope property:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder($index)">{{btnText}}</a>
```

And add some logic to your controller, that will specify text for button:

```
if (newItem){
  $scope.btnText = 'Submit';
}else{
  $scope.btnText = 'Update';
}
```