# How to select button in template generated by ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change the label of button to **Update** if, template has already data come from back-end, but for new-template label of button should be **Submit**. There templates are created by using ng-repeat, please see the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview).

```
 <div class="col-md-12" style="bottom:10px" >   
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in fields">  
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-4"> 
              <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Field1</label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input data-ng-model='field.field1' class="chosen-select input-md form-control sme-input-box"/>
              </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="col-md-4">          
            <label  class="col-md-12 control-label">Field2</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">            
                <input ng-model='field.field2'  class="chosen-select input-md form-control sme-input-box"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">            
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="removeTemplate($index)">Remove</a>   
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder($index)">{{addandUpdate}}</a>   
            </div>                      
        </div>  
      </div>      
      <div class="col-md-3" style="top:5px">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="cloneTemplate()">Add</a>   
      </div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you had asked similar question here & i gave answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34708673/2435473

Comment: 'field in fields' seems should be 'template in templates'?
just use some property for your template (like id) and in view template check it like {{field.id ? 'Update' : 'Submit'}}